# oracle sql converter CharacterConverter12Byte problem in jdbc

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, character

I was working on a simple GUI script yesterday using jdbc in eclipse.
When I went to run the program, I got a pop up screen asking me about character conversion in jdbc.

I had no idea what this was and neither did my professor (no surprise there).

Now every time I run a program, even one that doesn't use SQL I get the same error.

```
0
- 2127527632
189000
-1875869392
-2127527632
258
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at oracle.sql.converter.CharacterConverter12Byte.toOracleCharacterWithReplacement(CharacterConverter12Byte.java:253)
at oracle.sql.converter.CharacterConverterGB18030.main(CharacterConverterGB18030.java:1119)
```

That's the output I get from it. It may as well be reading binary because I have no idea what it means.

Can anyone explain what's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there are no answers yet, here's how I fixed the problem.

I tried accessing the drivers of Oracle and finding anything to do with charconverters. Since I couldn't find any I fixed the problem by changing the workspace in Eclipse. So it must have been something to do with the location on the disc.